# How to skip next statements and jump to the other statement in debugging visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual studio 2003, 2008 show a red dot on the left at line where we set a break,  When the process stops at the break line, I can hoover and drag the yellow high lighted to skip some statements.  I don't see it in visual studio 2010.  In 2010, I have to right click and set break, there is no cursor or thing to grab and move it to next statement.  How to skip a statement and jump to other statements.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know VS 2010 has same functionality as VS 2008. I mean you can drag yellow highlighter to next statements to skip them.

Comment: that what I thought.  I tried, but nothing there to drag.  I googled for a while and people talked about the red dot in visual studio 2010 like 2008, even in MSDN.  Is it just me?  Thanks

Comment: It is under Tool/option/selection margin and indicator margin.  The default is not displaying